# Rails 4 - Wicked PDF attachment on email through an observer

Tags: ruby-on-rails, email-attachments, observers, wicked-pdf

I'm trying to send an email from an observer that has a pdf attachment.  I'm trying to render_to_string in the observer, but can't get AbstractController to function properly. Anyone have an example how they've done it?

**-- Update --**

I was unable to get render_to_string to work properly in the observer, so integrated rendering the pdf into the mailer.

```
class PdfMailer < ActionMailer::Base

  default from: 'admin@example.org'
  layout 'mailer'

  def invoice(invoice)
    @user = User.current_user
    @invoice = invoice
    attachments["#{Date.today.strftime('%Y%m%d')}-invoice-#{invoice.invoice_number}"] = {
      mime_type: 'application/pdf',
      content: rendered_pdf(invoice)
    }
    mail to: @user.email, subject: 'Invoice'
  end

  private

  def rendered_pdf(invoice)
     WickedPdf.new.pdf_from_string(rendered_view(invoice)) 
  end

  def rendered_view(invoice)
    render_to_string partial: 'invoices/show.pdf.erb', locals: { invoice: @invoice } 
  end

end
```

Comment: Do you have more details on how it is not working? Observers have been removed from Rails 4, assuming you are using the rails-observers gem?